# How to code the summation of a function in C?

Tags: c

EDIT: I've added the main, factorial, and trapGamma function to give the full picture but I am specifically talking about the for loop for iSum in the I function.

Basically I've run out of ideas and exhausted everywhere I know of to find an answer to this.  I need to code a program that will compute a complex function which represents an M/M/1 queue.

The function includes sub functions such as calculating the integral of a gamma function and computing factorials.  I've written all the code for the computations but my sum is giving me huge numbers when I would expect nothing higher than about .35

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double I(int k, double t);
double trapGamma(double z);
unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned int n);

int main()
{
    int k;
    int i = 0;
    double dt = 0.1;

    printf("Ikx = [ \n");

        for (t = 14.0 ; t <= 15.0; t += dt)
        {
            printf("%f " , t);

            for (k = 1 ; k <= 10 ; k++)
            {
                I(k, t);
                printf("%f " , I(k, t));
            }
            printf("\n");

        }

        printf(" ];\n");

    return (0);
}


double I(int k, double t)
{
    unsigned long long int x;
    unsigned int n = 20;
    double numerator, y, pow1, c;
    double iSum;
    double Ix;
    int i = 0;

    iSum = 0.0;
    Ix = 0.0;

    a = .25 * pow(t , 2);
    b = pow(a, i);
    x = factorial(n);
    y = trapGamma(k + i + 1);

    iSum = (b / (x * y));

    //This is the sum loop that I'm having trouble with, I've broke the iSum equation down for my own readability while coding right above this comment

    for (i = 0; i <= 100 ; i++)
        {
        iSum += i;
        }

    Ix = (pow((.5 * t), k) ) * iSum;
    return Ix;
}


/*
I've checked both the factorial and trapGamma functions and they are giving me the expected results. 
*/

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n - 1));
}


double trapGamma (double z)
{

    int i , N = 100;
    double gamma;
    double a = 0.0;
    double b = 15.0;
    double x1, x2, y1, y2;
    double areai;
    double w = (b - a) / N; 
    gamma = 0.0;

    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            x1 = a + ((i - 1) * w); //the left bound point
            x2 = a + (i*w); //the right bound point
            y1 = pow(x1,z - 1)*exp(-x1); //the height of our left bound
            y2 = pow(x2, z - 1)*exp(-x2); //the height of our right bound
            areai = ((y1 + y2) / 2.0) * (x2 - x1);
            gamma += areai;
        }
    return gamma;
}
```

This is building upon another project where I used a bessel function to create the M/M/1 queue over a 60 second span so I can see what this one is supposed to be.  I've checked both my trapGamma and factorial functions results on there own and they are both working as expected.

How are summations supposed to be coded?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you expect this loop `for (i = 0; i <= 20 ; i++) { iSum += i; }` to do? (It actually just adds a constant value of 210 to `iSum`!)

Comment: With `n = 20;` just how big do you think `x = factorial(n);` is? With `n` being an `unsigned int`, that won't fit, but due to unsigned wrap (reduced modulo) it will wrap back to `0` when `UINT_MAX`  is reached. Your `iSum` usage is fine, you have problems trying to store a value greater than `UINT_MAX` in `x`.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the modified [Bessel function I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1)? Can we assume k>= 0?

Comment: So in order; 1) i'm trying to use a for loop to sum the first 20 terms of iSum, I can't figure out how to sum each term rather than just adding a constant value.   2) The full factorial function header is unsigned long long int factorial (unsigned int n) and when I tested its output I got the correct answer up to n = 20.   3) Yes, I'm calculating the modified Bessel function I and k will run from 1 - 10 in the main body of the program

Comment: Please note that, since C99, `<math.h>` provides [`tgamma`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/tgamma). Also, compare the [results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HEt0K6QoNHoMK7iF) with those of `trapGamma`.

Comment: Took your advice and checked the tgamma against my trapGamma and they are the same for k <= 5 and then begin to diverge at k >= 6 but not by enough that i would expect any major difference in results.  For this project I need to use the less accurate trapGamma function that I've coded.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent of the posted code is to calculate the [modified Bessel function I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), there are some pitfalls and useful semplifications to be aware of. Given

[image]

Trying to calculate the factorial, the value of the Gamma function, their product and the powers *separately* for each term of the sum leads to integer overflow sooner than later.

It's better to *update* the value of each addend of the sum instead.

Also, given that `k` is a whole, we have Γ(n) = (n - 1)!

[image]

The addends are increasingly smaller and, after some iterations, too small to be added to the sum, given the limited precision of type `double`.

```
// Evaluates x^k / k! trying not to overflow
double power_over_factorial(double x, int k)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= k; ++i )
    {
        result *= x / i;
    }
    return result;
}

#define MAX_ITERS 20

double modified_Bessel_I(int k, double x)
{
    x /= 2;
    const double xx = x * x;
    double partial = power_over_factorial(x, k);
    double old_sum, sum = partial;
    int m = 1;
    do
    {
        old_sum = sum;
        partial *= xx / ((m + k) * m);
        sum += partial;   
    }
    while ( old_sum != sum  &&  ++m < MAX_ITERS );

    return sum;
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qQxa6k7kr5Bdhstu).

Comment: So I've been trying to work with this for the last 2 hours and while the concept is helpful I can seem to figure out how to apply it to my code.  I'm really trying to learn how to handle the summation in my double I (int k, double t) function with a for loop.  Is a for loop not going to work for this summation?

Comment: @nontype What do you mean? I used a loop too. A `do{} while()` isn't really that different from a `for(){}`, the important thing is what's inside. The loop in your code only adds `i` to `iSum`, while it should be something like `iSum += pow(...) * factorial(...) / gamma(...)`. I don't know why you left those outside it.

Comment: Okay, it just clicked with the summation.  Thank you so much for the help,  I think i'm still making an error somewhere in my calculation but the summation is doing what I would expect now.